# Azure AD application - User assignment required option enabled, newly added user can't login

Tags: azure, azure-activedirectory

We have an application setup to use Azure AD. The 'User Assignment Required' option is enabled because we wanted to restrict access to a specific set of AD users. It's working fine for existing users.

However, we recently added a new user from the Enterprise Applications section for that app, and he is not able to log in. He gets the 'Need admin approval' message. When we disable the 'User Assignment Required' option, it works fine for him as well.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you enable the 'User Assignment Required' option you have to give Admin Consent for that Applications permissions. When enabling this option normal users can not give consent on their own anymore, they only can give consent when that option is off. But you probably want that option on so you can control who can access the Application so you need an Admin (Global admin, Cloud Application admin or Application Admin) to give the consent for that App.